# Flush state to disk ubuntu

Tags: disk

I was reindexing blockchain and I got this message:

Unable to open file /home/ki/.bitcoin/rev00502.dat ERROR: Flush: fail to open file 502 *** Flushing undo file to disk failed. This is likely the result of an I/ error

Any ideas how to solve it?

Comment: Disk full? Any errors in the journal?

Comment: Disk is not full. In the journal I get: pan_unix (sudo:autth) couldnt open /etc/securety: no such a file o directory.              .: EXT4-fs error (device sda1): ext4_lookup:1707 inode #4982778: comm bitcoind: iget: checksum invalid

Comment: That ext4 error sounds bad. Do a fsck on /dev/sda1.

Answer (score 1):

From your comments it appears that your ext4 filesystem on `/dev/sda1` has errors, so the first thing is to do a filesystem check.

Since this is probably your root filesystem, it might be a good idea to do this while it is not active, so I suggest you use a live filesystem (Ubuntu on a USB stick, i.e. any not-too-old Ubuntu installation image written to a USB stick) to do that:

Boot the live filesystem, open a shell window and first find out what device your normal disk is; the `lsblk` command will be useful:

```
sh@balrog:~$ lsblk
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0 931,5G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0  97,7G  0 part /win/boot
└─sda2   8:2    0 833,9G  0 part /win/app
sdb      8:16   0 931,5G  0 disk 
├─sdb1   8:17   0     2G  0 part 
├─sdb2   8:18   0    30G  0 part /hd-root-18-04
├─sdb3   8:19   0    30G  0 part /hd-root-14-04
├─sdb4   8:20   0     1K  0 part 
└─sdb5   8:21   0 869,5G  0 part /work
sdc      8:32   0 232,9G  0 disk 
├─sdc1   8:33   0     2G  0 part [SWAP]
├─sdc2   8:34   0    30G  0 part /
├─sdc3   8:35   0    30G  0 part /ssd-root-20-04
└─sdc4   8:36   0 170,9G  0 part /ssd-work
sr0     11:0    1  1024M  0 rom
```

It is possible that the USB stick you just booted from is now `/dev/sda`; in that case, your normal disk will be `/dev/sdb`. Check the `blkid` output and compare the partition sizes to what you'd expect. Then start a (forced) filesystem check:

```
sudo fsck -f /dev/sdb1
```

(or `fsck -f /dev/sda1`, depending on which disk is which)

If it reports errors and asks if it should fix them, answer `y` for "yes". If it reports so many errors that it becomes tedious to answer them, terminate it with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> and restart it with the `-y` parameter added:

```
sudo fsck -f -y /dev/sdb1
```

(or `-fy` for short)

When this is done, shut down the live system; or you can do it a bit more brutally with

```
sync
sudo reboot
```

`sync` writes all pending disk buffers.

If this problem reappears, check with the `smartmontools` if your disk starts getting hardware problems.